# How to connect signals to slots between 2 shared libraries

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have 2 shared libraries. I the first one I implemented some core components for a particular class.

```
class CoreClass : public QObject
{

  Q_OBJECT

public:
  void doSomeStuff();

signals:
  void aSignal();
}
```

In the second one I implemented some widget specific options for that class:

```
class WidgetClass : public QWidget
{

  Q_OBECJT

public:
  WidgetClass();

private:
  CoreClass* __core;
}
```

Now I want to connect the signal from `CoreClass` to the slot of `WidgetClass` derived from `QWidget`.

```
WidgetClass::WidgetClass()
  : __core(new CoreClass)
{
  connect(__core, &CoreClass::aSignal, this, qOverload<>(&QWidget::update));
}
```

I want the `widget` to be updated whenever the `__core` emits the signal `aSignal`, but it doesn't.

**==================== UPDATE =========================**

That was my fault. There is no problem in connection. I just missed calling the function, which calls the `connect` function.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't updated?

Comment: Are you sure the signal is emitted?  Try connecting it to a lambda that provides some debug output.

Comment: Also note that calling `QWidget::update` won't invoke `QWidget::paintEvent` immediately -- it simply schedules a repaint/update.

Comment: @vahancho because I have some updates on `CoreClass` when the widget gets clicked and it emits the signal, which has to cause to frontend changes

Comment: @G.M. Yes, I'm sure. I have debugged

Comment: @G.M. I have tried to set the `repaint` slot instead of `update` with no positive result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems correct, you should try these things to be sure though.

`QObject::connect` return a [QMetaObject::Connection](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject-connection.html) that can cast to `bool` so you can verify at runtime if the connection has been created as expected.

Also verify that you're creating the connection between the object that emits the signal and not a different instance, otherwise it will never work.

Comment: Guys, I'm so sorry. It was my bad. Missed to execute code which makes the connection. Thank you all.